# Add tablerowheader and tablecolheader to the toolbar menu and and the table context toolbar

Tags: tinymce

I would like to add the two items to the table menu from the main toolbar and the menu in the context toolbar of the table in TinyMCE 6.
For the table context toolbar, I was able to modify the config value `table_toolbar` like so:

`mceConfig.table_toolbar = 'tableprops tabledelete | tableinsertrowbefore tableinsertrowafter tabledeleterow | tableinsertcolbefore tableinsertcolafter tabledeletecol | tablerowheader tablecolheader';`

This added the two buttons at the end there but I cannot find something similar for the table menu from the main toolbar. How can I add those two buttons there?